# How to don't pass any value to methods in PHP

Tags: php

I have a simple class with 1 method that accepts a parameter.

```
class ArticleController
{
    public function show(Article $article)
    {
        // some logic here
    }
}
```

and i want to use it in this way:

```
$articleController = new ArticleController;
$articleController->show();
```

as you see i didnt pass any value to the method "show". but since php7 is out and it forces to pass that value(dependency), is there any way that i dont pass that value to the method and still can use it without error ?
my PHP Version = 7.1.8

Comment: You can modify the method declaration so that it only expects an optional parameter. But even then, the method code might not work as you expect. Post the full method code in the question to make sure.

Comment: **Note:** If `$article` is meant to be used within the class and you set it to `null` it will throw errors.

Comment: Yeah that's an option but what i want exactly is that i dont pass any value to the parameter not having an optional parameter. If you'are familiar with laravel, it uses this feature but i dont know what is he doing in the back scene.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*The behaviour described in the question is not specific to PHP 7. It works the same on PHP 5 as well.*

You can set a [default value](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.default) for argument `$article` (making it optional this way) but if you set it to `NULL` then you have to make sure you handle the value properly in the method:

```
class ArticleController
{
    public function show(Article $article = NULL)
    {
        if (isset($article)) {
            // some logic here, $article is an object
        } else {
            // $article is NULL, cannot use it as an object
        }
    }
}
```

When you call `show()` without passing it a value, the argument `$article` is initialized with the default value (`NULL` in this example).

```
$controller = new ArticleController();
$news       = new Article();

$controller->show($news);
// inside the show() method, $article is set to $news

$controller->show();
// no argument was passed, $article is NULL inside show()
```

Comment: do you mean that if i use show(Article $article) it will set $article to null ? if no then i dont wanna set my variable to null

Comment: If `$article` is not set (meaning it has not been passed) it will set the value of it to `null` thereby making any original use for `$article` useless.

Comment: @VeRJiL No, the default value is used when the function is called *without* a value for the argument.

Comment: but in laravel we dont pass any value to the controller's method and the methods doesnt have any default value.

Comment: Laravel is a framework written in PHP. You asked a question about PHP, I provided you an explanation about how PHP works. Laravel is not involved in the PHP behaviour in any way, nor it can influence the way PHP works. If your question doesn't match how Laravel works (I don't know and I really don't care how it works) then either you change your code to match the Laravel rules or replace Laravel with a framework that matches your coding style better.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP you can set your your values like:

```
class ArticleController
{
  public function show(Article $article = null)
  {
    // some logic here
  }
}
```

Comment: This answer - though correct - does not cater for the fact that an error can be thrown if the class continues to execute while `$article` is `null`.

Comment: Yeah that's true.